# Angular js 404 error with angular template variables even when using ng-if on page load?

Tags: html, variables, angularjs-directive, http-status-code-404, angular-ng-if

Why is this

```
INFO     2018-02-16 21:32:33,192 module.py:788] default: "GET /%5B%7Binstance.file_url%7D%5D HTTP/1.1" 404 233
```

showing up in my terminal given that `instance.file_url` is used in

```
<a class="source" href="[{instance.file_url}]" title="[{instance.file_url}]" target="_blank">source</a>
```

(Note: `[{}]` is not an error: `{{}}` conflicts with jinja2 so I changed angular's)

and contained with in a `<section ng-if="instance">` tag??

How do I fix this? Or is it normal? Any debugging tips?

I have no idea why it's querying for values I'm not asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try changing the `href` to `ng-href`? Then the anchor tag won't have a `href` attribute until AngularJS interpolates the value, which shouldn't happen until that `ng-if` resolves to truthy.

Here's the ngHref documentation for reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: I found out I actually needed to replace src with ng-src in other code, which this post gave me the idea for. Thanks!